# I want an indication (in a textbox) that a folder doesn't exist

Tags: c#

update: I want a text box to say "Cache exists" if a folder exists and "Cache deleted" if the folder doesn't exist

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pathWithEnv = @"%USERPROFILE%\.rsclient";
        var aslcache = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(aslcache, true);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string curFile = @"%USERPROFILE%\.rsclient";
        Console.Write(Directory.Exists(curFile) 
            ? textBox1.Text = "Cache exists." 
            : "Cache has been deleted.");
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
Updated the code with Lews Therin's answer.

```
private void updateTextBox()
{
   string curFile = @"%USERPROFILE%\.rsclient";
   textBox1.Text = Directory.Exists(curFile) ? "Cache exists." :
   "Cache has been deleted.";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var pathWithEnv = @"%USERPROFILE%\.rsclient";
   var aslcache = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);
   System.IO.Directory.Delete(aslcache, true);
   updateTextBox();
}
```

I get the error:

> Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' does not contain a definition
>   for 'textBox1_TextChanged' and no extension method
>   'textBox1_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Users\4p\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\cache deleter
>   csharp\cache deleter csharp\Form1.Designer.cs 53 71 cache deleter
>   csharp

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: You should probably store the file name gobally, rather than have it copied in different variables within your methods.

Comment: The question could have been simplified to "How do I set the text content of a TextBox", maybe?!

Comment: What should the user type in Textbox1? Changing Textbox1.Text as the user types in Textbox1 may an idea to rethink.

Comment: Why did you edit your question with my answer? Can you rollback and tell me the error message on the comments section on the answer I gave? I've rolled back for you.

Comment: If you are getting the "Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'textBox1_TextChanged' and no extension method..." it's possible you didn't delete the code section where the textBox1_TextChanged is bound to an event handler.  search for "textBox1_TextChanged" to find that line of code (most likely in `InitializeComponent()`) and remove it. Then recompile.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
private void updateTextBox()
{
    string curFile = @"%USERPROFILE%\.rsclient";
    textBox1.Text = Directory.Exists(curFile)? "Cache exists." :
        "Cache has been deleted.";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pathWithEnv = @"%USERPROFILE%\.rsclient";
    var aslcache = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(aslcache, true);
    updateTextBox();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Form constructor check if the file exists using 
File.Exists(path) [MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx]

```
if (File.Exists(path)) {
textbox.text = "file exists"
}else {
textbox.text = "file doesn't exist"
{
```

After you have deleted the file you can change the textBox text again if you need it.